Azure Function deployment
I want to deploy a function to an Azure Function App using a git repository and an Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline already exists and it works (the file are being deployed in the Function App), but I cannot see any functions in the Function App.
The file structure is the following:
root/
├─ my_function.py
├─ my-function.json
├─ requirements.txt
And the my-function.json file if the follwing:
{
  "scriptFile": "my-function.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}


Azure Functions must have the following file structure:
function1-name/
├─ __init__.py
├─ function.py
function2-name/
├─ __init__.py
├─ function.py
By doing this and implementing an Azure DevOps pipeline you can deploy the code to an Azure Function App and it will recognize every folder as a specific function
